# Filtering Unstructured data with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame import from CSV , post filtering from that file my temporary DF is below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 df = pd.read_table("/DATA/testing/ADNS/ADNS_01_40405.txt", sep=" ", 
               error_bad_lines=False,skiprows=1,header=None,skipinitialspace=True)
 df.columns = ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVE","EIGH","NINE","TEN","ELEV"]
 tmp = df.ONE.str.contains("topoff", na=False)

#tmp = df.ONE.str.isdigit()
TOP_IP = df.loc[tmp]
TOP_IP
```

```
                                                   ONE    TWO THREE             FOUR          FIVE  SIX SEVE EIGH NINE  TEN  ELEV
483  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD02.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  86400    IN                A   203.88.1.58  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
484  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD02.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  86400    IN                A  10.169.19.89  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
486  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD03.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A      203.88.3.11           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
487  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD03.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     10.169.18.16           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
489  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD06.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A      203.88.1.49           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
490  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD06.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     203.88.2.190           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
492  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD07.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     203.88.4.132           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
493  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD07.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     203.88.2.190           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
495  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMRELICLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A    112.110.84.25           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
496  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMRELICLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A    112.110.84.29           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
498  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgBARODACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A     203.88.4.156           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
499  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgBARODACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A      203.88.16.7           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
501  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgBHUJCLOUD.node.epc.mnc005.m...     IN     A    112.110.84.35           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
502  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgBHUJCLOUD.node.epc.mnc005.m...     IN     A    112.110.84.39           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
503  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgDL02.node.epc.mnc005.mcc404...     IN     A      203.88.1.37           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
505  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgGODHRACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A    112.110.84.20           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
506  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgGODHRACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A    112.110.84.24           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

post filter i need only ONE and FOUR field where data are present but first Two records are not in the shape .

below output is required .

```
                                                   ONE    TWO THREE             FOUR          FIVE  SIX SEVE EIGH NINE  TEN  ELEV
483  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD02.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     203.88.1.58            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
484  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD02.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     10.169.19.89           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
486  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD03.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A      203.88.3.11           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
487  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD03.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     10.169.18.16           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
489  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD06.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A      203.88.1.49           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
490  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD06.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     203.88.2.190           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
492  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD07.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     203.88.4.132           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
493  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD07.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...     IN     A     203.88.2.190           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
495  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMRELICLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A    112.110.84.25           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
496  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMRELICLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A    112.110.84.29           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
498  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgBARODACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...     IN     A     203.88.4.156           NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

I have tried isdigit and lot of other function and not able to do so . 
any help will appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Idea is use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) only rows with numeric in `TWO` column filtered by [`Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html), last reassign original first column:

```
orig = df['ONE'].copy()
mask = df['TWO'].astype(str).str.isdigit()

df[mask] = df[mask].shift(-1, axis=1)
df['ONE'] = orig
```

---

```
print (df)

                                                   ONE TWO THREE  \
483  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD02.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  IN     A   
484  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD02.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  IN     A   
486  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD03.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  IN     A   
487  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD03.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  IN     A   
489  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD06.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  IN     A   
490  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD06.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  IN     A   
492  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMD07.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  IN     A   
493  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMD07.node.epc.mnc005.mcc40...  IN     A   
495  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgAMRELICLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...  IN     A   
496  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgAMRELICLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...  IN     A   
498  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgBARODACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...  IN     A   
499  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgBARODACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...  IN     A   
501  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgBHUJCLOUD.node.epc.mnc005.m...  IN     A   
502  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgBHUJCLOUD.node.epc.mnc005.m...  IN     A   
503  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgDL02.node.epc.mnc005.mcc404...  IN     A   
505  topoff.pgw-s5s8.epgGODHRACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...  IN     A   
506  topoff.sgw-s5s8.epgGODHRACLOUD.node.epc.mnc005...  IN     A   

              FOUR FIVE  SIX  SEVE  EIGH  NINE  TEN  ELEV  
483    203.88.1.58  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
484   10.169.19.89  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
486    203.88.3.11  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
487   10.169.18.16  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
489    203.88.1.49  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
490   203.88.2.190  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
492   203.88.4.132  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
493   203.88.2.190  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
495  112.110.84.25  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
496  112.110.84.29  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
498   203.88.4.156  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
499    203.88.16.7  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
501  112.110.84.35  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
502  112.110.84.39  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
503    203.88.1.37  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
505  112.110.84.20  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  
506  112.110.84.24  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, Thanks four you great help . Could you please explain bit about this line .        
 ** df[mask] = df[mask].shift(-1, axis=1)  **

Comment: @Thecoder - Sure, `df[mask]` is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - it filter rows by mask. So here rows with digits by `TWO` column. And only for these rows is used shift function - with axis=1 and `-1`, so all columns are shift to left.